# Nuxt3 (SSR) useCookie Composable With Vercel Cache-Control

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, vercel, nuxt3

I am currently building a site that is using Nuxt3 frontend (SSR) hosted on vercel, with a Strapi CMS backend (hosted on Digital Ocean for what it's worth.) I am having trouble with the nuxt composable `useCookie`, it works perfectly locally but when I deploy it onto Vercel it doesn't appear to work as intended all the time.

I am using `useCookie` to set a light/dark mode cookie for my site. The snippet of code looks like:

```
const colorMode = useCookie("colorMode", {
  default: () => "light",
  path: "/"
});
let colorModeState = useState("colorMode", () => colorMode.value || "light");
useHead({
  htmlAttrs: { class: colorModeState.value }
});
function setColorMode() {
  if (process.client) {
    if (colorModeState.value == "light") {
      document.documentElement.classList.replace("dark", "light");
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.replace("light", "dark");
    }
  }
}
function toggleColorMode() {
  colorModeState.value = colorModeState.value == "light" ? "dark" : "light";
  colorMode.value = colorModeState.value;
  setColorMode();
}
```

Setting a cookie, passing it into state so that I use it in other components. Appending the html class with the use of `useHead`. On page refreshes through it doesn't always display the correct mode, I can see the cookie value may be set to `light` but it will still display `dark`. I think it may be around the cache-control options I have in place in vercel.

My current test headers are: `s-maxage=1, stale-while-revalidate=59`, I think maybe the cache is caching the cookie value also because if I change the color mode but wait over 60 seconds before refreshing it correctly keeps the colorMode. However I don't know how to get useCookie to work without setting the cache-control headers very low.

Any suggestions would be great appreciated.